# Retrieving times from two TimePickers in DialogFragments

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I have an input form in an activity where I'd like to retrieve the start time and end time of an event.  I am using a timepicker displayed in a dialog fragment to get the start time and return it to the main activity, but how do re use the same logic to retrieve the end time of the event? My code:

Main Activity:

```
public class AddEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
private int pickerHour = 0;
private int pickerMin = 0;

//code ommitted for length

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String amOrPm = "am";
    pickerHour = hourOfDay;
    pickerMin = minute;
    String minutesString = "";
    if (hourOfDay > 12){ //translate to 12 hr clock. Little workaround to get both timepicker and am/pm label to show up correctly.
                amOrPm = "pm";
                pickerHour-=12;
            }
            if (pickerMin < 10) {
                minutesString = "0"; //fix weird bug where only one zero is shown on times ending in :00
            }
    startTimeView.setText(pickerHour + " : " + minutesString + pickerMin + " " +amOrPm );
}
```

TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
int hour,minute;
private Activity mActivity;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
    try {
        mListener = (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnTimeSetListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(mActivity, mListener, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mActivity));
}
```

}

I need to be able to differentiate between the start time and the end time, but I am not sure how to differentiate them without repeating myself. I am pretty new to Java and Android. Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly something as simple as a boolean?

```
public class AddEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
    ...
    boolean isSettingStartTime = true;


    //code ommitted for length

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        ...

        if (isSettingStartTime) {
            startTimeView.setText(pickerHour + " : " + minutesString + pickerMin + " " +amOrPm );
            isSettingStartTime = false;
        } else {
            endTimeView.setText(pickerHour + " : " + minutesString + pickerMin + " " +amOrPm );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was simple and it worked - the only time there is a problem is if the user tries to set the end time before setting the start time, as in this case the boolean isn't switched correctly. For my purposes right now this works just fine though. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, there are potential issues and it was based as an illustration of how to solve your current requirements. Ideally you would store the start time as a `Date` object (for example) then when the user enters end time, create another `Date` object for that and compare the two to ensure the end is later than the start. It's not too difficult to do but was beyond the scope of what you'd asked for. There are plenty of examples out there for comparing date/time so I'm sure you'll find something if/when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This would require you being able to retrieve the `TimePicker` from your `TimePickerFragment`

You either need to get the `TimePicker` instance when you create both `TimePickerFragment`s and store them in two fields such as `startTimePicker` and `finishTimePicker`.

Then when the `TimePicker` is passed in through the `onTimeSet` you then check to see which `TimePicker` it is like so.

```
if ( timePicker == startTimePicker ) {
      startTimeTextView.setText....
} else {
      finishTimeTextView.setText...
}
```

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more? I'm not sure what you mean by "You either need to get the TimePicker instance when you create both TimePickerFragments and store them in two fields"